# Need help replacing swprintf

Tags: c++, string

I am using some cross platform stuff called nutcracker to go between Windows and Linux, to make a long story short its limited in its support for wide string chars. I have to take the code below and replace what the swprintf is doing and I have no idea how. My experience with low level byte manipulation sucks. Can someone please help me with this?

Please keep in mind I can't go crazy and re-write swprintf but get the basic functionality to format the pwszString correctly from the data in pBuffer. This is c++ using the Microsoft vc6.0 compiler but through CXX so it's limited as well.

The wszSep is just a delimeter, either "" or "-" for readabilty when printing.

```
HRESULT BufferHelper::Buff2StrASCII( 
   /*[in]*/ const unsigned char * pBuffer, 
   /*[in]*/ int iSize,
   /*[in]*/ LPWSTR wszSep,
   /*[out]*/ LPWSTR* pwszString )
{
 // Check args
 if (! pwszString) return E_POINTER;

 // Allocate memory
 int iSep = (int)wcslen(wszSep);
 *pwszString = new WCHAR [ (((iSize * ( 2 + iSep )) + 1 ) - iSep ) ];
 if (! pwszString) return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

 // Loop
 int i = 0;
 for (i=0; i< iSize; i++)
 {
  swprintf( (*pwszString)+(i*(2+iSep)), L"%02X%s", pBuffer[i],  (i!=(iSize-1)) ? wszSep : L"" );
 }
 return S_OK;
}
```

This takes whats in the pBuffer and encodes the wide buffer with ascii. I use typedef const unsigned short* LPCWSTR; because that type does not exist in the nutcracker.

I can post more if you need to see more code.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you format that code? And perhaps elaborate on what exactly you need to do -- Do you need to make it so that swprintf points to a different function than it normally does? The problem you have is that a code transformation tool is borking on swprintf? Link to the tool?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by format the code? 

Contents of pBuffer looks like: 

0740740630310005405404303203000000000000000000000000000

It's big endian hex. So 0 74, is wide t char and so on.

The final format looks like this 0074 for the one char in pwszString. Its hard to make this clear I will try, if the wchar is 7400 it swaps it big endian in another fucntion to make it 0074 in pBuffer and then puts the ascii representation into pwszString so 00 byte would be ascii 0 and 74 would be ascii 74 or t and when you print the char from pwszString it looks like 0074 on the stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand exactly what you are looking for, so I've guessed.

As the tag was "C++", not "C" I have converted it to work in a more "C++" way.  I don't have a linux box to try this on, but I think it will probably compile OK.

Your description of the input data sounded like UTF-16 wide characters, so I've used a std::wstring for the input buffer.  If that is wrong, change it to a std::vector of unsigned chars and adjust the formatting statement accordingly.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cerrno>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#if !defined(S_OK)
    #define S_OK 0
    #define E_OUTOFMEMORY ENOMEM
#endif

unsigned Buff2StrASCII( 
                const std::wstring &sIn, 
                const std::wstring &sSep, 
                std::wstring &sOut)
{
    try
    {
        std::wostringstream os;

        for (size_t i=0; i< sIn.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i)
                os << sSep;
            os  << std::setw(4) << std::setfill(L'0') << std::hex
                << static_cast<unsigned>(sIn[i]);
        }
        sOut = os.str();
        return S_OK;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc &)
    {
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t szIn[] = L"The quick brown fox";
    std::wstring sOut;
    Buff2StrASCII(szIn, L" - ", sOut);
    std::wcout << sOut << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was more of what I wanted to achieve, here is what I eventually used (I got help from someone who does this all the time):

if(pBuffer[j] == NULL) // No data, so ascii encode the null (0x30)
{ //cout << "Found NUll: " << j << endl;
  
            // First wide char 0 NULL
            *ctemp = '0';
            ctemp+=1;
            *ctemp = NULL;
            ctemp+=1;
            // Second wide char 0 NULL
            *ctemp = '0';
            ctemp+=1;
            *ctemp = NULL;
            ctemp+=1;
   }

That was the main idea. I will try yours as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that didn't format well. I want to mark yours as my answer but I am not sure how?

Comment: @Dixon There should be a hollow tick that you can click on.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use the WSTR types at all in nutcracker / the linux build? Most unixes and linux use utf-8 for their filesystem representation, so, in the non windows builds, you use sprintf, and char*'s.

Comment: I tried that but I can't get it to work the same way. I have to send the results of that function over to a server and it expects it to be wide, so I can't.